# Inverse of g(a, b) = (a + b, a - b)?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, inverse

As the question title suggests, does $g(a, b) = (a + b, a - b)$ have an inverse? If so, what is it?

Comment: $a=\frac12((a+b)+(a-b))$ and $b=\frac12((a+b)-(a-b))$.  Are you familiar with matrices?

Comment: $u=a+b$, $v=a-b$ is a linear equation system which can be solved for $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $h(a,b) = (u(a,b), v(a,b))$ and we need $g(h(a,b)) = g(u(a,b), v(a,b)) = (u(a,b) + v(a,b), u(a,b) - v(a,b) = (a,b)$ and $h(g(a,b)) = h(a+b, a-b) = (u(a+b,a-b),v(a+b,a-b)) = (a,b) $

So we nut $u(a,b) + v(a,b) = a$ while $u(a,b) -v(a,b) = b$.  And we need $u(a+b, a-b) = a$ and $v(a+b, a-b)) = b$>

$u(a,b)+v(a,b) = a$ and $u(a,b) - v(a,b) = b$ so $[u(a,b)+v(a,b)] + [u(a,b) - v(a,b) ] = 2u(a,b) = a+b$.  So $u(a,b) = \frac {a+b}2$.

And  $[u(a,b)+v(a,b)] -[u(a,b) - v(a,b) ] = 2v(a,b) = a-b$.  So $v(a,b) = \frac {a-b}2$.

So $h(a,b) = g^{-1}(a,b) = (\frac {a+b}2, \frac {a-b}2)$.

We can verify that.

$g(\frac {a+b}2, \frac {a-b}2 ) = (\frac {a+b}2 + \frac {a-b}2, \frac {a+b}2 - \frac {a-b} 2) = (a,b)$.

And $g^{-1}(g(a,b)) = g^{-1}(a+b, a-b) = (\frac {(a+b) + (a-b)}2, \frac {(a+b)-(a-b)}2)= (\frac {2a}2, \frac {2b}2) = (a,b)$.

It holds.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in a comment by [Martin R](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/42969/martin-r), we have

$$u=a+b\tag1$$

and $$v=a-b\tag2.$$

Adding $(1)$ and $(2)$, we get $u+v=2a$, and subtracting $(2)$ from $(1)$, we get $u-v=2b$.

If you solve these for $a$ and $b$, you will get $g^{-1}(u,v)$.